# Why is the derivative of $e^x$ equal to $e^x$? And why the derivative of $a^x$ is equal to $ a^x\ln a$?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I don't understand the reasoning behind it. I was trying to figure it out with the chain rule in the case of $e^x$, but the I would get $(X(e)^x-1)(e^x)$ and I can't find the reasoning by my own

Comment: If the derivative is with respect to $x$, then $x$ is in the exponent.  Please don't confuse this with the derivative of $x^n$.

Comment: You say something rather alarming when you wrote `(X(e)^x-1)(e^x)`... it looks as though you are remembering how $\dfrac{d}{dx}[x^n] = n\cdot x^{n-1}$.  That only has to do with when $x$ is the base... not when $x$ is the exponent.

Comment: $$
\frac{d}{{dx}}a^x  = \frac{d}{{dx}}e^{x\log a}  = e^{x\log a} \frac{d}{{dx}}(x\log a) = e^{x\log a} \log a = a^x \log a
$$

Comment: As for "*why is the derivative of $e^x$ equal to $e^x$*"... to answer that we must first ask you how do you have $e$ defined?  How do you have $e^x$ defined?  This should in most circumstances be a matter of definition

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  To start with, surround math expressions by `$` signs.

Comment: There's a lot of info at the duplicate target. But if you still need help with this after reading all those answers, then you can edit this question and try to explain what you need, and answer the questions JMoravitz asked you. There are several different ways to approach this topic, and it's hard for us to help you without knowing stuff like how you have defined $e$.

Answer (score 2):

These are different!

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^n = n x^{n-1}, \quad \text{ Here }x\text{ is being raised to a power}.$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x, \quad \text{ Here }x\text{ is the exponent}.$$
Let's show this:
$$\frac{d}{dx} e^x = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=  \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(e^{h}-1)}{h}e^x$$

Now we need a definition for $e^x$.  Here is one:

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+ \cdots$$

Now $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^h-1}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}1+h+\frac{h^2}{2}+\cdots=\lim_{h\to0}e^h = 1,$$ so $$\frac{d}{dx} e^x =e^x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps unsatisfyingly, $f(x) = e^x$ is sometimes *defined* as the unique function such that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = f(x)
$$
with $f(0) = 1$.

From there, we have
$$
a^x = (e^{\ln a})^x = e^{x \ln a}
$$
so that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} a^x = \frac{d}{dx} e^{x \ln a} = e^{x \ln a} \frac{d}{dx} (x \ln a) = (\ln a) e^{x\ln a} = (\ln a) a^x
$$
by the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Derive $e^x$ and $x^n$ from first principles to see why they are what they are.

$$f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} {f(x+h) - f(x) \over h}$$